# Define rule for set of child elements

Tags: html, css

As an example, I want `labels` and `input` fields within a certain `class` to have similar rules.

**CSS**

```css
.SpecialBox input, label{
    background-color: green;
}
```

When I use the previous code, what it actually does it apply the rules to any input field within a SpecialBox and *ALL* labels because the ruleset applies each of the comma separated items:

- `.SpecialBox input`
- `label`

I can modify the selector to clarify both items individually

```css
.SpecialBox input, .SpecialBox label{
    background-color: green;
}
```

In which case I get the desired result, but at the expense of being concise

Here's a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/JJqQu/) to demonstrate

*Is there a way to apply a set of rules to all children of a particular selector, or am I forced to repeat the parent element selector?*

I believe there is a way to do this with **SASS** or **LESS**, but I'd prefer to do this with straight CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For only the `input` and `label` elements, you would have to repeat the selector.

If you want all children, you can use the wildcard: `.SpecialBox *`  This will apply the style to ALL of the children.

Answer (score 0):

just use the class `.SpecialBox *`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `*` selector:

```
.SpecialBox  *
```